# Extract string after colon or parenthesis with regex in python

Tags: python, python-re

input:

```
Subject: Representation of Territories? (Was: Re: The $11,250,000,000,000 lunch)
```

output:

```
Representation of Territories
```

input:

```
Subject: Re: Top Ten Responses to Ed's Top Ten Lists
```

output:

```
Top Ten Responses to Ed's Top Ten Lists
```

Comment: Please, don't spam irrelevant tags (removed). Also it is completely unclear what you're asking for, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: why doesn't the first output contain "(Was: Re: The $11,250,000,000,000 lunch)"? What is the logic behind this? If you want "Everything after colon", that part definitely counts. And where's the part about extracting string after parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an optional capture group:

```
import re

text_1 = "Subject: Representation of Territories? (Was: Re: The $11,250,000,000,000 lunch)"
text_2 = "Subject: Re: Top Ten Responses to Ed's Top Ten Lists"

regex = re.compile(r"Subject:\s"
                   r"(?:\w{2}:\s)?"  # Optional capture group
                   r"((\w+[']?\w+?\s?)+\w)"
                   r"\??",
                   re.I
                   )

res_1 = re.search(regex, text_1).group(1)
res_2 = re.search(regex, text_2).group(1)

print(res_1)
print(res_2)
```

Returning:

```
Representation of Territories
Top Ten Responses to Ed's Top Ten Lists
```

Addition, as requested in the comments:

```
text_3 = "Subject: Re: F<O>CUS/HEALTH: ONE PAYER SYSTEM B.S."
regex_3 = re.compile(r"(.*:\s)+(.*)")
res_3 = re.search(regex_3, text_3).group(2)
print(res_3)
```

Returning:

```
ONE PAYER SYSTEM B.S.
```

Comment: My pleasure :) Enjoy your Python programming.

Comment: #Gustav Rasmussen, i have 18345 text files, i have to read all files and extract subject from file(like mention in above in question). Your solution is good. i have get subject from most of files. but some file throw "None".
Example:-
"Subject: Re: F<O>CUS/HEALTH: ONE PAYER SYSTEM B.S."
output should be :-ONE PAYER SYSTEM B.S.

Comment: The answer has been updated. Consider splitting into several regex patterns for readability.